# How to access container (SkyDns) via exposed port at 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp (docker0) from another container? Docker 1.7.1, Centos 7

Tags: docker, skydns

I am trying to setup SkyDNS/SkyDock within one docker host for multiple containers. So each container should use dns at 172.17.42.1 (/etc/resolv.conf).

I followed setup part from [README.md](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock) :

```
docker run -d -p 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp --name skydns crosbymichael/skydns -nameserver 8.8.8.8:53 -domain docker
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock --name skydock crosbymichael/skydock -ttl 30 -environment dev -s /docker.sock -domain docker -name skydns
```

and the test via

```
docker run -d --name redis1 crosbymichael/redis
docker run -t -i crosbymichael/redis-cli -h redis1.redis.dev.docker
```

and it is not working. I can ping from the "redis-cli" container host 172.17.42.1 but cannot access 172.17.42.1:53/udp.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Centos 7 ("Minimal install") in default installation creates many rules/chains in iptables. I don't know why, as I am not a sys admin. So after I flushed all chains and rules via:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

and then restarted docker service `service docker restart`
it all started to work.